# understanding Logic statements and their negation

Tags: logic

for example if Im given(the world is Naturals): $∀a∀b((∀x(x\text{ is prime})) \Rightarrow ∀c, ac=bc))$
can i prove it's True by negation(so called negation?)? saying exists $a$ and $b$ s.t $∀x(x $ is prime)) and exists $c$ s.t $ac \not=bc$, so this is false since $∀x(x \text{ is prime}))$ is false, so the original statement is true? is it fine proving such things that way? because honestly the original statement doesnt really make any sense.

Comment: Yes the firts part asserting that evry number is prime is false, thus the complete statement is true.

Answer (score 0):

> saying exists a
> and b
> s.t ∀x(x
> is prime)) and exists c
> s.t ac≠bc
> , so this is false since ∀x(x is prime))
> is false, so the original statement is true?

No. This doesn't prove anything, at least in the way its been written.

We consider the statement:
$$\forall a \forall b: ((\forall x (x \text{ is prime})) \Rightarrow \forall c, ac = bc$$
I've added the colon to help the spacing so that the statement is easier to read, it's not a necessity for logical statements. How do we prove that $a \Rightarrow b$ is true? We can either a) prove its true by showing that when $a$ is true $b$ must also be true or b) assume that $a \Rightarrow b$ is false, meaning $b$ is false and $a$ is true, and show that that is impossible.

So we prove by contradiction: Assume: $\forall a \forall b: ((\forall x (x \text{ is prime})) \Rightarrow \forall c, ac = bc$ is false. Then it must be that their exists a case that $\forall a,b,c:  ac = bc$ is false and $\forall x (x \text{ is prime} )$ is true. However, $\forall x (x \text{ is prime})$ is always false, so it cannot be true, and this is a contradiction since it must be true. Hence, our original statement is true. Q.E.D.